# Firebase Subcollection Search - Solution or take a new approach

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using Google Firebase Firestore to manage an email scheduling system for a large number of clients. I am mindful that as the Firestore document increases my current approach will use all available Firebase Function resources and timeout. I wanted to reach out and see if the community had any feedback on my current approach, or suggestions for alternative pathways.

**Current Approach**

I have a Firestore collection called `user-schdule` which has the following structure:

```
user-schedule 
   UID
      send_item
           slug
           send_time
           title
```

A user (denote day UID) can have multiple `send-item` collections. An example would be:

```
user-schedule 
   hjhsdhjdhjk1
      2023-11-14
           slug: 2023-11-14
           send_time: 2023-11-14 00:23
           title: "Hello World"
      2023-11-15
           slug: 2023-11-15
           send_time: 2023-11-15 00:23
           title: "Hello World3"
```

Note: Not every user has an item to be sent each day, and the schedule for each user can and does change.

I am currently using the following abstract code to extract users:

```js
async function getDueUsers(date) {
  let due_users = [];
  const user_uid = await admin.firestore().collection("user_schedule").get(); // get user data

  await user_uid.forEach(async (s) => {
    const user_sch = s.data();
    if (user_sch[date]) {
        due_users.push({ uid: s.id, title: user_sch[date]["title"] });
    }
  });

  return due_users;
}
```

This works very well and extracts only those that have an item due. However I am mindful that the `.get()` command can soon exhaust all resources.

**Future approaches**

I do wonder if it may be more advisable to create a new collection which is shallow and has the following structure.

```
email-schedule 
  2023-11-14
      UID1
      UID2
      UID3
  2023-11-15
      UID1
      UID3
```

Where I would store only those UID's which are due, and pull the required elements for each user as required.

Comment: It's not clear to me which parts of your data structure are subcollections and which are fields in a document, so you may want to update your question to highlight that. --- Aside from that, loading an ever growing amount of data will indeed lead to time-outs over time (not to mention, ever increasing costs). Instead you should [run a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) that only returns the data that you want to modify, so the documents that meet the `if (user_sch[date]) {` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Puf replied above, I would also caution you that the "array helper functions" (.forEach, .map, .reduce, etc.) are not "asynchronous aware" and it is a bad idea to pass async functions to them unless you really, really, really know what you are doing.  It is typically far safer to use standard `for` or `for ... of` loops.  [This article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-deal-with-async-await-in-the-array-functions-4f592f1c0091) gives a decent overview of the problem.

Now, back to the problem at hand: it would be much better if you structured your documents to have data within such that you could ***query*** for matching documents rather than iterate over every document every single time.  Something along the lines of:

```js
let collRef = admin.firestore().collection("user_schedule");
let q = collRef.where("scheduleDatesArray", "includes", date);
let querySnap = await q.get();
```

This way you would only be fetching documents from "user_schedule" that actually have scheduled items for the given date.

This might mean you need to duplicate the dates within your document:

- the array of "scheduledDatesArray" - an array of strings of dates that this document has items for
- the schedule item information itself

Assuming that `hjhsdhjdhjk1` in your example data above is a Document and that the data nested underneath is data within that one Document, then you'd have:

```json
{
  "scheduledDatesArray": [
    "2023-11-14",
    "2023-11-15"
  ],
  "2023-11-14": {
    "slug": "2023-11-14",
    "send_time": "2023-11-14 00:23",
    "title": "Hello World"
  },
  "2023-11-15": {
    "slug": "2023-11-15",
    "send_time": "2023-11-15 00:23",
    "title": "Hello World3"
  }
}
```

that would be returned for `getDueUsers("2023-11-15")` but would not be returned for `getDueUsers("2023-11-16")` because there is nothing scheduled for that date for this user.